# Vue.js v-bind & v-model binding issue in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've use `v-bind` and `v-model` in my form input field. but when i run `npm run dev` command it's show the: `v-bind:value="user.name" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally error`.

in `v-bind` i'm bind my `props` value and in `v-model` use a local variable.

Here is my Code Sample:

```
<label>Name</label>
      <input name="name" class="form-control" v-bind:value="user.name" v-model="username"/>
 props:{

  user:{
    type:[Array,Object],
    required:true,
  },

},
data(){
  return{

   username:'',
   email:'',
   id:''
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

`v-model="username"` is just a shorthand for:
`:value="username" @input="username = $event"`

and as a result you have:

```
<input
  name="name"
  class="form-control"
  :value="user.name"
  :value="username"
  @input="username = $event"
/>
```

it is error - vue don't know what put into input

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule `v-bind:value` conflicts with `v-model` because it also binds to `value`. The exceptions to that rule are check boxes and radio buttons where having both is valid (and may be where you got the idea from). In those cases `v-model` actually binds to the `selected` property.

```
<!-- Valid, binds to selected -->
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" :value="currentFruit" v-model="selectedFruits" />
<input type="radio" name="animal" :value="currentAnimal" v-model="selectedAnimal" />

<!-- Not valid, both bind to value -->
<input type="text" :value="currentName" v-model-"currentName" />
```

Comment: what can i do now , for overcome my issue??

Comment: Just use `v-model` without the additional value binding. To get the initial value you can write something like `username: this.user.name`.

Comment: `username:this.user.name` don't show any value, but when use `{{user.name}}` it's show value. that's problem. for your concern my child model is `modal` component.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two different data sources (i.e. v-bind and v-model at the same time) bind to the same input; If you are looking to initialize the input from props, you can set the data prop `username` with `this.user.name` without using `v-bind:value`:

```
<input name="name" class="form-control" v-model="username"/>
 props:{

  user:{
    type:[Array,Object],
    required:true,
  },

},
data(){
  return{

   username: this.user.name,
   email:'',
   id:''
  }
}
```

Comment: Check how the `user` props looks like, does it contain a `name` field?

Comment: yes, it's contain `name` field, i've tested it in view like `{{user.name}}` its show output.

Comment: It seems to work for me at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qas4z0n6/